# Get name from separate table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables which store data:

```
create table exchanges
(
    exchange_long_name  text,
    exchange_id         bigint
);

create table active_pairs
(
    exchange_id           integer
);
```

I would like to get the list of `active_pairs` and translate the value `exchange_id` using the value `exchange_long_name` into table `exchanges`  How this can be implemented using JOIN?

Comment: I'd expect a table named `active_pairs` to have 2 columns.

Comment: hm... when we make a query can we implement `exchange_id` to be translated to `exchange_long_name`?

Comment: JOIN the table where the long name is stored. (JOIN twice if you have two different exchange id's.)

Comment: Can you show me the code example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    active_pairs.exchange_id,
    exchanges.exchange_long_name
FROM active_pairs
INNER JOIN exchanges USING (exchange_id)
```

or if you prefer not to use `USING` you can join like this

```
INNER JOIN exchanges ON exchanges.exchange_id = active_pairs.exchange_id
```

Please note that your datatypes do not match: `active_pairs.exchange_id` is an `int` while `exchanges.exchange_id` is a `bigint`.